# my footer chances if i put something above it

Tags: html, css

I first made my design for my website but now I want to put in some content , above my footer, my footer is becoming bigger.

How do I fix this?

[image: My code with content]

[image: My site with content]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [how to ask a qood question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is because your footer position is fixed with a fixed height. Also, next time post your code here. (or a JsFiddle) Not a link.

Net begonnen met html zie ik.

Comment: I am coding for about a year but this is the first time that I am making something what is going to be online. but in what do I have to change it?

Comment: You can try removing the position fixed and bottom 0. And just make the div above it bigger.